# Separable version of Banach-Alaoglu

Tags: functional-analysis

My notes say that the theorem of Banach-Alaoglu states the following:
If $X$ is a normed separable space, then every bounded sequence in $X'$ has a weak-* convergent subsequence.

How is this equivalent to the usual formulation from Wikipedia, etc - i.e. the closed unit ball being weak-*-compact, for a (not necessarily separable) normed space $X$? Or is it a special case?

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is separable, then the closed unit ball in $X'$ is metrizable with respect to the weak-$\ast$ topology. Hence compactness, given by Banach-Alaoglu, implies sequential compactness.

Answer (score 2):

It's a special case. If $X$ is separable then it's not hard to show that the closed unit ball of $X'$ is *metrizable* in the weak-* topology (note $X'$ itself is not weak-* metrizable), so compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness in that case.